# Append data to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am using push function to append my items to an array in PHP

```
 foreach($request->input('students') as $student) {
        
            $rules[] = [$students['name'] => 'required'];
  }
```

when i print the rules it outputs something like this, :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Amit]=> required
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [James] => required
        )
)
```

but i want it's structure like, i want to remove its indexes to make it complete associative:

```
   Array
        (
            [Amit]=> required
        )

     Array
        (
            [James] => required
        )
```

Comment: That's impossible: PHP arrays need to have keys, they aren't optional. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: The nearest you can get (assuming no duplicates) is `$rules[$students['name']] ='required';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have and what you want is both the same structure, most probably you want this:

```php
foreach($request->input('students') as $student) {
     $rules[$student['name']] =  'required';
}
```

which outputs with:

```php
Array
(
    [Amit] => required
    [James] => required
)
```

Note it's hard to guess without knowing your `$request->input('students')` structure...